# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch') at getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
  22 | export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  23 |   const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
> 24 |   const products = await client.fetch(query);
     |                         ^
  25 |   const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
  26 |   const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);        
  27 | }
```

I am trying to fetch Data but I keep getting this.

Below is the client and I have imported in in the index.js file  using
import  client from "../lib/client";:

```
import sanityClient from  '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client  = sanityClient({
    projectId: '1elz6lsg',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion : '2022-03-10',
    useCdn : 'true',
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN,
});
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source)=>builder.image(source);
```

Comment: Where is client defined ?

Comment: I have just added it

Comment: try with await client?.fetch(query);

Comment: @BahubaliAk  i did and i get this error :   ~   Error serializing `.products` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. ~

Comment: Since `client` is not the default export just modify the import in `import { client } from '../lib/client';` instead of `import client from '../lib/client';`

Comment: @Nick I Just did that and I am getting another error:  Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Comment: @Gift it means that you're rendering something (some props or some variable shared by server and client) on the client that is different from server and client. Next.js considers this as an error but it's not always that, check your code and if something makes sense to differ from server and client just disable the error check or fix your code to match both server and client